# efficiently finding an object that falls within a certain number range

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops, time

Here's my basic problem: I'm given a `currentTime`. For example, 750 seconds. I also have an array which contains 1000 to 2000 objects, each of which have a `startTime`, `endTime`, and an `_id` attribute. Given the `currentTime`, I need to find the object that has a `startTime` and `endTime` that falls within that range -- for example, `startTime : 740`, `endTime : 755`.

What is the most efficient way to do this in Javascript?

I've simply been doing something like this, for starters:

```
var arrayLength = array.length; 
var x = 0;
while (x < arrayLength) {
 if (currentTime >= array[x].startTime && currentTime <= array[x].endTime) {
  // then I've found my object
 }
x++;
};
```

But I suspect that looping isn't the best option here. Any suggestions?

**EDIT: For clarity, the `currentTime` has to fall within the `startTime` and `endTime`**

**My solution:** The structure of my data affords me certain benefits that allows me to simplify things a bit. I've done a basic binary search, as suggested, since the array is already sorted by startTime. I haven't fully tested the speed of this thing, but I suspect it's a fair bit faster, especially with larger arrays.

```
var binarySearch = function(array, currentTime) {

  var low = 0;
  var high = array.length - 1;
  var i; 

  while (low <= high) {
    i = Math.floor((low + high) / 2);

    if (array[i].startTime <= currentTime) {

      if (array[i].endTime >= currentTime ){
        // this is the one
        return array[i]._id; 

      } else {
        low = i + 1;
      }
    }

    else {
      high = i - 1;
    }
  } 

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Clarification needed, I think. Which of those three times has to fall within the other two?

Comment: Well if your array is sorted, you could always use binary search to improve run-time

Comment: Sorry, the currentTime has to fall within the startTime and endTime.

Comment: Never mind, I can see from your code that you want current time in the middle despite that fact that your sample data uses 756, which is _not_ within 740..755.

Comment: Yikes. that was a silly mistake!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to tackle this problem depends on the number of times you will have to call your search function.

If you **call your function just a few times**, let's say `m` times, go for linear search. The overall complexity for the calls of this function will be `O(mn)`.

If you **call your function many times**, and by *many* I mean more than `log(n)` times, you should:

- Sort your array in `O(nlogn)` by `startTime`, then by `endTime` if you have several items with equal values of `startTime`
- Do [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find the range of elements with `startTime <= x`. This means doing **two** binary searches: one for the `start` of the range and one for the `end` of the range. This is done in `O(logn)`
- Do linear search inside `[start, end]`. You have to do linear search because the order of `startTimes` tells you nothing about the `endTimes`. This can be anywhere between `O(1)` and `O(n)` and it depends on the distribution of your segments and the value of `x`.

**Average case:** `O(nlogn)` for initialization and `O(logn)` for each search.

**Worst case:** an array containing many equal segments, or segments that have a common interval, and searching in this interval. In that case you will do `O(nlogn)` for initialization and `O(n + logn) = O(n)` for search.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a problem for [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your search array is long-lived and relatively constant, the first iteration would be to sort all the array elements by start time (or create an index of sorted start times pointing to the array elements if you don't want them sorted).

Then you can efficiently (with a binary chop) discount ones that start too late. A sequential search of the others would then be faster.

For even *more* speed, maintain separate sorted indexes for start and end times. Then do the same operation as mentioned previously to throw away those that start too late.

*Then,* for the remaining ones, use the end time index to throw away those that end too early, and what you have left is your candidate list.

But, make sure this is actually *needed.* Two thousand elements doesn't seem like a huge amount so you should time the current approach and only attempt optimisation if it is indeed a problem.

Comment: This only makes sense if there are many queries to the same array. Otherwise sorting the array by start time will take more time already (O(N log(N))) than the actual linear search. I.e. with sorting and binary search one will often be slower.

Comment: @LiKao, yes, but there's nothing in the question indicating one way or the other whether the array is an arbitrary one or long-lived. I'll clarify the answer for the latter one.

Answer (score 1):

From the information given it is not possible to tell what would be the best solution. If the array is not sorted, looping is the best way for single queries. A single scan along the array only takes O(N) (where N is the length of the array), whereas sorting it and then doing a binary search would take O(N log(N) + log(N)), thus it would in this case take more time.

The analysis will look much different if you have a great number of different queries on the same large array. If you have about N queries on the same array, sorting might actually improve the performance, as each Query will take O(log(N)). Thus for N queries it will require O(N log(N)) (the remaining log(N) gets dropped now) whereas the unsorted search will also take O(N^2) which is clearly larger. When sorting starts to make an impact exactly also depends on the size of the array.

The situation is also different again, when you update the array fairly often. Updating an unsorted array can be done in O(1) amortized, whereas updating a sorted array takes O(N). So if you have fairly frequent updates sorting might hurt.

There are also some very efficient data structures for range queries, however again it depends on the actual usage if they make sense or not.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is not sorted, yours is the correct way.

Do not fall into the trap of thinking to sort the array first, and then apply your search.

With the code you tried, you have a complexity of **O(n)**, where **n** is the number of elements.

If you sort the array first, you first fall into a complexity of **O(n log(n))** (compare to [Sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)), in the `average case`.

Then you have to apply the binary search, which executes at an average complexity of **O(log_ 2(n) - 1)**.

So, you will end up by spending, *in the average case*:

**O(n log(n)** + **(log_2(n) - 1))**

instead of just **O(n)**.

Comment: Your analysis is correct in so far that you assume a single query only. On multiple queries for the same array the analysis may look completely different and sorting may make sense.

Comment: What you say is correct, but from the question that the OP asked, it seems to me that he does not need to query that array more than once.

Answer (score 1):

An [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) is a data structure that allows answering such queries in O(lg n) time (both average and worst-case), if there are n intervals total.   Preprocessing time to construct the data structure is O(n lg n); space is O(n).  Insertion and deletion times are O(lg n) for [augmented](https://github.com/vvondra/Interval-Tree) interval trees.   Time to answer all-interval queries is O(m + lg n) if m intervals cover a point.   [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) describes several kinds of interval trees; for example, a centered interval tree is a tertiary tree with each node storing:

> • A center point
>   • A pointer to another node containing all intervals completely to the left of the center point
>   • A pointer to another node containing all intervals completely to the right of the center point
>   • All intervals overlapping the center point sorted by their beginning point
>   • All intervals overlapping the center point sorted by their ending point

Note, an interval tree has O(lg n) complexity for both average and worst-case queries that find one interval to cover a point.  The previous answers have O(n) worst-case query performance for the same.  Several previous answers claimed that they have O(lg n) average time.  But none of them offer evidence; instead they merely assert that average performance is O(lg n).  The main feature of those previous answers is using a binary search for begin times.  Then some say to use a linear search, and others say to use a binary search, for end times, but without making clear what set of intervals the latter search is over.  They claim to have O(lg n) average performance, but that is merely wishful thinking.  As pointed out in the wikipedia article under the heading *[Naive Approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Naive_approach)*,

> A naive approach might be to build two parallel trees, one ordered by the beginning point, and one ordered by the ending point of each interval. This allows discarding half of each tree in O(log n) time, but the results must be merged, requiring O(n) time. This gives us queries in O(n + log n) = O(n), which is no better than brute-force.