# python: if a number falls within a certain range, return the string corresponding to that range

Tags: python, range, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe (df1) with a column of numbers, say:

- [[2,7,17]]

and another dataframe (df2) with a list of ranges, defined by two columns - start position (p1) and end position (p2). Each range in this dataframe has a corresponding string (name) in another column on the same line, say:

- p1 [[1,6,11,20]]
- p2 [[5,10,15,16]]
- name [['A','B','C','D']]

I need to find the range(A, B, C or D) the numbers from df1 fall within. In this example, 2 falls between 1 and 5, so would return 'A', whereas 7 falls between 6 and 10 so would return 'B'. Nothing falls between 11 and 15 so 'C' would not be returned, but D would be returned as it falls between 16 and 20.

Note: Although both A and B end at a position that is higher than the start position (p1 is lower than p2), D starts at a position higher than its end (p2 is lower than p1). I would still like to call 17 in df1 as falling within range D, even though the range is going the other way.

Although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063489/efficiently-finding-an-object-that-falls-within-a-certain-number-range) article seems to be asking a similar question in java, I have not found anything similar in python, other than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624095/return-if-a-number-is-between-two-values-python).

Thankyou in advance, and please keep in mind I am a bit of a newbie!

Comment: Is this about plain-python or some package like `numpy` or `pandas`?

Comment: hi tobias_k, I was actually importing my data etc. with pandas before, but instead imported with 'numpy.genfromtext' when using Jérôme's solution below. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a draft with a few ideas. I use numpy. And I used arrays, but you could use columns as specified in your question.

```
import numpy as np

df1 = np.array([2,7,17,0])
p1 = np.array([1,6,11,20])
p2 = np.array([5,10,15,16])
name = np.array(['A','B','C','D'])

result = []

for d in df1:

    categories = np.logical_or(
        np.logical_and(d >= p1, d <= p2),
        np.logical_and(d <= p1, d >= p2))

    result.append(name[categories[0]] if np.any(categories) else '')

print(result)
```

If a number falls into several categories, only one is returned. If it falls into none, an empty string is returned (you may prefer to return `None` instead).

The range going both ways is managed by the logical_or.

The "trick" is to use boolean array addressing. `categories` is an array of booleans (e.g. [True, False, False, False]) where each elements is True if and only if the data is in the corresponding category: first element True means it is in category A, etc.

`name[categories]` is then an array containing all elements of `name` for which corresponding element in `categories` is True. Other elements are stripped.

e.g. `np.array([1,2,3])[np.array([True, False, True])]` -> `array([1,3])`

`name[categories[0]]` is the first (there may be several) category to which the number belongs.

Comment: Thanks Jérôme - very helpful answer. I made one small change and it worked perfectly (I deleted the [0] after 'result.append(name[categories[0]]...')

Comment: Glad I helped. Deleting the [0] means that, for each point, instead of getting a category as a string, you'll get an array with all the categories it belongs to. If you do that, you probably don't need the if `np.any` test either: if the point belongs to no category, you'll get an empty array. So the line would become: `result.append(name[categories])`